# How to run a function based on a specific status code returned from axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

before `jquery ajax`, we can do this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: param.method || 'get',
        url: param.url || '',
        dataType: param.type || 'json',
        data: param.data || '',
        success(res){
            if(res.status === 0){
                typeof param.success === 'function' && param.success(res.data, res.msg)
            }else if(res.status === 10){
                _this.doLogin()
            }else if(res.status === 1){
                typeof param.error === 'function' && param.error(res.msg)
            } 
        },
        error(err){
            typeof param.error === 'function' && param.error(err.statusText)
        }
    })
```

in above code, for example when `res.status===0`, execute `typeof param.success === 'function' && param.success(res.data, res.msg)`

if in `axios`, how to handle this custom defined status and execute Corresponding operation?

Answer (score 1):

They can be done two ways, given:

```
yourFunctionCall() {
    alert('hello!');
}
```

1) [interceptors](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#interceptors), which happen on every request

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {

    if (response.status === 0) {
        yourFunctionCall();
    }

    return response;
}, function (error) {
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

2) or, in the actual `axios` call itself (depending on your setup)

```
axios({
    ...
    method:'get',
    url:'<your-http-call>',
    ...
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.status); // via status code
    console.log(response.data.status); // via response status code 

    if (response.status === 0) {
        yourFunctionCall();
    }

}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error.response); // log error response
});
```